# How to store an image url received from server to variable in angular js and ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, image, url, ionic-framework

I am trying to get my image url from response object and store it in a variable here is my code for getting the image url from server

```
$http.post("http://aflaree.com/apmsservice/securityService.svc/AvailableFacility",loginID)
      .success(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.facility);
        console.log(response.FacilityImage);
        $scope.img = response.FacilityImage;
        console.log($scope.img);          
      })
      .error(function(response){
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Here is my [response](http://plnkr.co/edit/hGDH27mZBgIEVHq6j4x5?p=catalogue) for the above post method.

Here is my html where i am planing to display image

```
<div >
    <img ng-src="{{img}}">
</div>
```

**Issues**

I am able to store or view my log for any field from response except **FacilityImage** field.

some how if i am able to store the image into **$scope.img** then using two way data binding will be able to show my image in html page

if there is any other way to make access of that image url form **FacilityImage** please let me know how to show that image to my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FacilityImage is an attribute of facility, therefore you have to access it like this:

```
response.facility.FacilityImage
```

Hope this helps!

UPDATE: actually event a level deeper, as facility is an array with multiple facilities, so assuming you pick the first one:

```
response.facility[0].FacilityImage
```